# What are the relationships between twisted.cred.portal.IRealm, Portal and avatar

Tags: http, twisted, basic-authentication

I'm trying to use Twisted's HTTP basic authentication to control access to some protected resources.

According to some articles, it is necessary to use three important concepts: Realm, Portal and avatar. Now I'm wondering if the Realm and avatar is one to one correspondence.

Let's look at an example

```
import sys

from zope.interface import implements

from twisted.python import log
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import server, resource, guard
from twisted.cred.portal import IRealm, Portal
from twisted.cred.checkers import InMemoryUsernamePasswordDatabaseDontUse


class GuardedResource(resource.Resource):
    """
    A resource which is protected by guard 
    and requires authentication in order
    to access.
    """
    def getChild(self, path, request):
        return self


    def render(self, request):
        return "Authorized!"



class SimpleRealm(object):
    """
    A realm which gives out L{GuardedResource} instances for authenticated
    users.
    """
    implements(IRealm)

    def requestAvatar(self, avatarId, mind, *interfaces):
        if resource.IResource in interfaces:
            return resource.IResource, GuardedResource(), lambda: None
        raise NotImplementedError()



def main():
    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
    checkers = [InMemoryUsernamePasswordDatabaseDontUse(joe='blow')]
    wrapper = guard.HTTPAuthSessionWrapper(
        Portal(SimpleRealm(), checkers),
        [guard.DigestCredentialFactory('md5', 'example.com')])
    reactor.listenTCP(8889, server.Site(
          resource = wrapper))
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Of course I know the SimpleRealm is used to return the corresponding resource, e.g. GuardedResource in above example. However, I don't know what to do when there lots of resources to be guarded. For example, I have GuardedResource1, GuardedResource2 and GuardedResource3, maybe they need the same or different number of parameters when they are initialized; If so, is it necessary to implement SimpleRealm1, SimpleRealm2 and SimpleRealm3, respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone asked this same question on the Twisted mailing list, with very similar code samples - http://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-python/2015-December/030042.html - so I'll refer you to my answer there: http://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-python/2015-December/030068.html

> Rather than thinking of a resource as always existing and just needing to have a lock on it or not, consider the more flexible model (the one that cred actually implements) where a single Avatar object (in this case: the top IResource returned from SimpleRealm) is the top level of "everything the user has access to".  In other words, 'GuardedResource' should have a 'getChild' method which makes the determination if the user they represent (really, at least the avatarId should be supplied to GuardedResource.**init**) has access to other resources, and return them if so, and appropriate errors if not.
>
> Even the resources available to a not-logged-in user (see twisted.cred.credentials.Anonymous) is just another avatar, the one served up to unauthenticated people.
>
> So, if you have https://myapp.example.com/a/b/secure/c/d https://myapp.example.com/a/b/secure/c/d, https://myapp.example.com/a/b/secure https://myapp.example.com/a/b/secure would be the guarded resource, and then SecureResource.getChild("c", ...) would return "c", which would in turn return "d" if the logged-in user has access to it.

Hopefully this answer worked for you on the list :-).